# What's the different between drawableLeft and drawableStart in EditText?

Tags: android

At first I thought drawableStart would auto change the icon's location when I changed system language to Arabic, which is a language written from right to left. But when I did that, nothing happened. 
So I guess they are the same?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I'm not sure the answer above is correct. From my experimentation, the icon always ends up in the same place unless you change the language AND enable RTL support.

`drawableStart` and `drawableEnd` only start switching sides when you [enable RTL support](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) in API Level 17 and above.

> Change all of your app's "left/right" layout properties to new
>   "start/end" equivalents.
>
> - If you are targeting your app to Android 4.2 (the app's    targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 17 or higher), then you should
>     use “start” and “end” instead of “left” and “right”. For example,
>     android:paddingLeft should become android:paddingStart.
> - If you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2 (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 16 or less), then you
>     should add “start” and end” in addition to “left” and “right”. For
>     example, you’d use both android:paddingLeft and android:paddingStart.

Comment: This is the correct answer instead of the accepted one.

Comment: In my case when put image on drawableLeft of button it's visible when I put same image on drawableStart it Image get invisible
`<Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGgle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ggle_logo"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="@string/ggle"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                app:cornerRadius="10dp" />`