# Adding Drawable in textview produces weird behaviour

Tags: android, textview, drawable

When I try to add `Drawable` to a `Textview` it shows multiple Drawables in android 4.2.2 and works perfect on android 6.0

Here is my layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_mail"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_mail"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_call"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_call"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot attached]

NOTE : I need support for both ltr and rtl layout directions, thats why I added drawableLeft and drawableStart

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17284962/4700782) could answer also you. lemme know

Comment: Read this link . It might help you in coding. http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley thats what i have done, but it produces multiple drawable in android 4.x

Comment: @FebiMathew i have taken the screen shot from android 4.2.2 (sdk 17),but issue with drawable

Comment: looks like you have ltr in your app but rtl in the phone, could be? because the alignment is rtl but the text ltr

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley yes, but it display single images in android 6.0 and double in android 4.2.2

Comment: ok, this might be the problem.. try changing the layout to rtl in your app and check if it still shows the error

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley i added  android:layoutDirection="rtl" in layout and issue still exist

Comment: Try by adding android:supportsRtl="true" in your <application> tag in Manifest file.

Comment: @FebiMathew already added

Comment: you need to find where the problem comes from: in ltr they are still doubled? if you remove the drawablestart, it still shows? and if you remove the drawableleft?

Comment: in android 16 only single image visible which is in the left of text

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley when i remove drawablestart.no issues,but drawable will be always in left of text view

Comment: ok, and if you remove the drawableleft it has the same issue?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley when i remove drawableleft everything work fine,but IDE shows a warning "To support older versions than 17 you should add drawableLeft"

Comment: ok. which one is your minimun target api? i think you are trying in 4.3-4.4, right?

Comment: ok.. unfortunatly for you, you have to create two layouts. one for >= 17 without drawableleft and one for <17 with it, after that all will work fine probably

Comment: okey, thank you for guiding me @PierGiorgioMisley ,@FebMathiew

Comment: welcome, i'm not sure 100% btw, you should check online for something about multiple layout per version :)