# My drawableLeft disappear if I use passwordToggleEnabled (EditText)

Tags: android, xml, mobile, android-drawable

I'm trying to have beautiful EditText in my application and I would use DrawableLeft to add simple icon on each input.
Everything is ok but on the EditText "Password", I added the passwordToggleEnabled (The user can see the input if he clicks on the eye).
Adding this makes my drawableLeft disappear.

Have you and idea ? (Sorry for my poor english :-/)

[Capture with drawable left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYIOX.png)

[Capture with password eye](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhJep.png)

Here is my TextInputLayout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputPassword"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/EditTextHint"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputEmail">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/shapy_blue"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:drawableStart="@mipmap/picto_password_blue"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@color/shapy_blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.478"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.459" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Edit >> When I change the drawable color in Java, (on Focus listener)

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
    if(view == editTextEmail){
        editTextEmail.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.mipmap.picto_mail_white,0,0,0);
        editTextEmail.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    } else {
        editTextEmail.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.mipmap.picto_mail_blue,0,0,0);
        editTextEmail.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.shapy_blue));
    }
    if(view == editTextPasswordLogin){
        editTextPasswordLogin.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.mipmap.picto_password_white,0,0,0);
        editTextPasswordLogin.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    } else {
        editTextPasswordLogin.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.mipmap.picto_password_blue,0,0,0);
        editTextPasswordLogin.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.shapy_blue));
    }

}
```

Comment: `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` add this to your TextInputLayout

Comment: drawableLeft and drawableStart are not the same if API Level >= 17, RTL is enabled and a special Language with RTL flow is selected. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907618/whats-the-different-between-drawableleft-and-drawablestart-in-edittext And if you have closer look your icon is not gone it is on the right hand side - so that difference might be the problem.

Comment: I want to have both icon, drawable icon (lock) on the left and eye icon for toggle password visibility on the right. 
I already tried to change start to left

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_password"
```

in EditText with drawableLeft

This is my sample code

```
                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/show_password_selector"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        android:layout_width="180dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_password"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_password"
                        android:hint="Password"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

app:passwordToggleDrawable - Drawable to use as the password input visibility toggle icon.
I think due to its own drawable property its gone. Please set this drawable  and check.

Comment: set drawable left property dynamically and check.

Comment: I already do this because when I click on edittext, his color change and I set the drawable with the good color.
The debugger goes in the good function but nothing was set.

Comment: Done on main post

Answer (score 0):

If you're still faxing this issue, what fixed it for me was adding these lines to the inputlayout

```
app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
app:errorIconDrawable="@null"
```